# Cluetip plugin - Why don't urls work?

Tags: cluetip

After installing and configuring cluetip, i realized that the urls you hover over to see the tooltip don't work when you click on them. It's like this on all of their examples - http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ (tested in firefox and safari at least)

How can I enable the urls that invoke the tooltip to be clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After futher reasearch I found out there's a configurable variable in the cluetip javascript called 'clickThrough'. Assigning this to true enables the urls the hoverable urls to function.